# Movie that police officer is the bad guy

Tags: identify-this-movie

A long time ago, I watched a movie that started with a car chase, and the good guy says "he drives like a cop" and the bad guy was a cop. After that I dont really remember what happened, but I think the good guy was a famous actor, and maybe the bad guy too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the movie [Striking Distance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108238/combined) with Bruce Willis playing Det. Hardy. The line was to Hardy's father, also a police veteran, who was in the car while both were on the way to a police function. A radio call came out that the suspected serial killer was escaping, and the description of the car matched; they started chasing, too. See the quote [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108238/quotes).